# how to calculate simple CPU load by formula

Tags: operating-system

I missed a class and now I'm confused.
Im trying to solve this task:

```
On a server with 2 CPU are 3 processes running
They are waiting 10% of their time on I/O
How high is the CPU load
```

The only formula i got is

```
CPU-load of a 1 CPU system = 1 - p^n
p = %of time idle
n = number of processes
```

I have no clue how to account for the second CPU in the formula.
Or can i say a CPU runs 2 processes and the other only 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One processor is idle if 2 processes cannot run. The probability of one processor being idle is

.1 x .1 + .1 x .1 + .1 x .1 - .1 x .1 x .1

Both processors are idle if 3 processes cannot run. The probability of both processors being idle is:

.1 x .1 x .1

Is the question then whether one processor is idle or both processors is idle? If the former and one processor is running, to you count this as being half idle?

I am amazed at the useless busywork they put students through.

Comment: The question is so confusion for me. In the script it is written like this: An OS runs on a server, while operation 3 processes are running, they are waiting 10% for I/O. How high is the anticipated CPU load.

Comment: Forgot to include the 2 prossecors. After talking to the Prof. he told me its when the whole CPU is idle, so the probability is .1 x .1 x .1 thank you!